# How to write serving input function for Tensorflow model trained without using Estimators?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-ml

I have a model trained on a single machine without using Estimator and I'm looking to serve the final trained model on Google cloud AI platform (ML engine). I exported the frozen graph as a SavedModel using [SavedModelBuilder](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r1.11/api_docs/python/tf/saved_model/builder/SavedModelBuilder) and deployed it on the AI platform. It works fine for small input images but for it to be able to accept large input images for online prediction, I need to change it to accept b64 encoded strings (`{'image_bytes': {'b64': base64.b64encode(jpeg_data).decode()}}`) which are converted to the required tensor by a `serving_input_fn` if using Estimators.

What options do I have if I am not using an Estimator? If I have a frozen graph or SavedModel being created from SavedModelBuilder, is there a way to have something similar to an estimator's `serving_input_fn` when exporting/ saving?

Here's the code I'm using for exporting:

```
from tensorflow.python.saved_model import signature_constants
from tensorflow.python.saved_model import tag_constants

export_dir = 'serving_model/'
graph_pb = 'model.pb'

builder = tf.saved_model.builder.SavedModelBuilder(export_dir)

with tf.gfile.GFile(graph_pb, "rb") as f:
    graph_def = tf.GraphDef()
    graph_def.ParseFromString(f.read())

sigs = {}

with tf.Session(graph=tf.Graph()) as sess:
    # name="" is important to ensure we don't get spurious prefixing
    tf.import_graph_def(graph_def, name="")
    g = tf.get_default_graph()

    inp = g.get_tensor_by_name("image_bytes:0")
    out_f1 = g.get_tensor_by_name("feature_1:0")
    out_f2 = g.get_tensor_by_name("feature_2:0")

    sigs[signature_constants.DEFAULT_SERVING_SIGNATURE_DEF_KEY] = \
        tf.saved_model.signature_def_utils.predict_signature_def(
            {"image_bytes": inp}, {"f1": out_f1, "f2": out_f2})

    builder.add_meta_graph_and_variables(sess,
                                         [tag_constants.SERVING],
                                         strip_default_attrs=True,
                                         signature_def_map=sigs)

builder.save()
```

Answer (score 3):

Use a @tf.function to specify a serving signature.  Here's an example that calls Keras:

```
class ExportModel(tf.keras.Model):
    def __init__(self, model):
        super().__init__(self)
        self.model = model

    @tf.function(input_signature=[
        tf.TensorSpec([None,], dtype='int32', name='a'),
        tf.TensorSpec([None,], dtype='int32', name='b')
    ])
    def serving_fn(self, a, b):
        return {
            'pred' : self.model({'a': a, 'b': b}) #, steps=1)
        }

    def save(self, export_path):
        sigs = {
            'serving_default' : self.serving_fn
        }
        tf.keras.backend.set_learning_phase(0) # inference only
        tf.saved_model.save(self, export_path, signatures=sigs)

sm = ExportModel(model)
sm.save(EXPORT_PATH)
```

Comment: i have the exact same problem but i dont get your solution. Can you explain how to come from an already SavedModel to your solution?

Comment: Please ask this as a new question. I think you want to know how to change the serving function of an already exported SavedModel.

Answer (score 0):

First, load your already exported SavedModel with

```
import tensorflow as tf
loaded_model = tf.saved_model.load(MODEL_DIR)
```

Then, wrap it with a new Keras model that takes base64 input

```
class Base64WrapperModel(tf.keras.Model):
  def __init__(self, model):
    super(Base64WrapperModel, self).__init__()
    self.inner_model = model

  @tf.function
  def call(self, base64_input):
    str_input = tf.io.decode_base64(base64_input)
    return self.inner_model(str_input)

wrapper_model = Base64WrapperModel(loaded_model)
```

Finally, save your wrapped model with Keras API

```
wrapper_model.save(EXPORT_DIR)
```